# Use Different Spacing Values in UIStackView

Tags: uiview, autolayout, uistackview

Is there a way to use different values for the spacing between views within a `UIStackView`? As I understand it, the `spacing` property is used for all views (or rather the room between them). I was hoping to just set the top space constraint to some value for each view but this seems to be ignored. Any suggestion? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is no build in solution for this. So we went with spacer views. We just added plain `UIViews` with our desired heights as elements of the `UIStackView`. It's not beautiful but it does the trick.